# Why does my linebreak not work?

Tags: macros, templates, line-breaking

I have the following code:

```
\section{Questions}
\freequestion What is the largest (LOC) class in the project? \par

\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|S|S|S|S|S|X|}
  \hline
  & $--$ & $-$ & $-/+$ & $+$ & $++$ &\\
  \hline
  The necessary information was easy to find & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & The necessary information was hard to find\\
  \hline
  Information retrieval requires redundant user input  & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & Information retrieval does not require redundant user input\\
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}%
}

\freequestion Please share any other remarks or ideas for improving the
workshop or this survey: \par
```

And here the macro:

```
\def\freequestion#1\par{#1\par\nobreak
    \begingroup\nobreak
    \advance\leftskip by 2pc
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \par
    \medskip
    \endgroup
    }
```

Now I wanted to add a linebreak or two before and after the table in the middle, but I already tried `\\`, `\newline` or `\par` and `\parskip` but nothing worked. why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have line-breaks between paragraphs, especially not two (because there are no lines to break there). Don't change `\parskip` by yourself as long you know exactly what to your are doing.
Two `\par`s after each other act like one. Note that the empty line before `\freequestion` already creates an implicit `\par.`

If you want to change the spacing between the table and the surrounding paragraphs use `\bigskip` (also `\medskip` and `\smallskip`) in combination with `\par`.